# Change Layer in OpenLayers, GeoServer

Tags: openlayers, layers

Wish I could change the layers according to a certain selection criterion.

For this I made a select that acts an onchange event that normally should change what is seen on the map ....

But unfortunately this does not happen :(

Please help, I am very new to these things ....

Here is what I've done so far:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
          $("#id_primarie").change(function(){
               console.log('test');
               
               var id_primarie = $('#id_primarie').val();
               
                var teren = new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                              url:'http://127.0.0.1:10000/geoserver/ADMINISTRATIE/wms',
                              params: {'LAYERS': 'ADMINISTRATIE:teren', 
                                       'STYLES':'TEREN', 
                                       tiled:true, 
                                       transparent: true, 
                                       viewparams: 'id_primarie:'+id_primarie },
                              format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                              ratio: 1,
                              serverType:'geoserver'
                    })
                });
                
                map.addLayer(teren);
               
          })
      });
```

Use: OpenLayers: 6.4.3
Geoserver 2.15.1

UPDATE:

cod:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
          $("#id_primarie").change(function(){
               console.log('test');
               
               var id_primarie = $('#id_primarie').val();
               
               
                var map = new ol.Map({
                  target: 'map',
                  layers: [
                    new ol.layer.Tile({
                      source: new ol.source.OSM()
                    }),
                    new ol.layer.Tile({
                          source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                                  attributions: ['Powered by Esri', 'Source: Esri, DigitalGlobe, GeoEye, Earthstar Geographics, CNES/Airbus DS, USDA, USGS, AeroGRID, IGN, and the GIS User Community'],
                                  attributionsCollapsible: true,
                                  url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
                                  maxZoom: 16
                          })
                      }),
                  ],
          
                  view: new ol.View({
                    center: [469713.24, 505416.01],
                    zoom: 35
                  })
                });
                
                proj4.defs('EPSG:31700','+proj=sterea +lat_0=46 +lon_0=25 +k=0.99975 +x_0=500000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=krass +towgs84=28,-121,-77,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');                      
                ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
      
               
               
                var teren = new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                              url:'http://127.0.0.1:10000/geoserver/ADMINISTRATIE/wms',
                              params: {'LAYERS': 'ADMINISTRATIE:teren', 
                                       'STYLES':'TEREN', 
                                       tiled:true, 
                                       transparent: true, 
                                       viewparams: 'id_primarie:'+id_primarie },
                              format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                              ratio: 1,
                              serverType:'geoserver'
                    })
                });
                
                
                map.addLayer(teren);
               
          })
      });
```

Now he does what he needs only because the problem is that he puts the same map with different layers twice :(

Comment: Can you clarify if you are trying to remove one layer and add a different layer, or are you trying to change what records are displayed in a lyer.  With wms and Geoserver, you can change what records are displayed with a CQL filter.  See here:  https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html.  If you want to actually remove a layer and add a different layer, use ol remove layer.  Here is one of many stack exchange posts discussing how to remove a wms layer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838856/remove-layer-from-open-layers-not-working

Comment: I try to erase one layer and put another layer in its place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example `teren` should be global so you can remove the old layer before adding a new one

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
          var teren;

          $("#id_primarie").change(function(){
               console.log('test');
               
               map.removeLayer(teren);
               var id_primarie = $('#id_primarie').val();
               
                teren = new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                              url:'http://127.0.0.1:10000/geoserver/ADMINISTRATIE/wms',
                              params: {'LAYERS': 'ADMINISTRATIE:teren', 
                                       'STYLES':'TEREN', 
                                       tiled:true, 
                                       transparent: true, 
                                       viewparams: 'id_primarie:'+id_primarie },
                              ratio: 1,
                              serverType:'geoserver'
                    })
                });
                
                map.addLayer(teren);
               
          })
      });
```

But it would be better to keep the same layer and update it by calling updateParams

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
          var teren = new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                              url:'http://127.0.0.1:10000/geoserver/ADMINISTRATIE/wms',
                              params: {'LAYERS': 'ADMINISTRATIE:teren', 
                                       'STYLES':'TEREN', 
                                       tiled:true, 
                                       transparent: true, 
                                       viewparams: 'id_primarie:'+ $('#id_primarie').val() },
                              ratio: 1,
                              serverType:'geoserver'
                    })
                });
                
          map.addLayer(teren);

          $("#id_primarie").change(function(){
               teren.getSource().updateParams({
                   viewparams: 'id_primarie:'+ $('#id_primarie').val()
               });
          })
      });
```

Comment: thank you very much ! Can you help me to center after selection on geometries automatically when I make the selection?